# Do the principles of law need to be spelled out in the bill?

Tags: jurisprudence, theory-of-law

We have the following situation in Ukraine
Parliament has decided to change the number of employees of one of the authorities.

At the same time, they indicated in the bill that the government must adapt to these changes and within a set timeframe.

My question is as follows.
Why is it necessary to explicitly write in the text of the bill that the government must adapt.
I think it is the basis of legislation that all documents of the lower hierarchy must be harmonized with documents of the higher hierarchy.

[The bill law](https://zakon.rada.gov.ua/laws/show/3502-IX#Text).

Answer (score 2):

### Timing

Besides the fact **that** the rules have to be adapted, there is a crucial factor: **Time limits**.

The law spells out when the government has to do certain steps: There are dates when specified numbers of additional personnel may be employed under II.2, and there are time limits of one month to deliver a report and suggestions in II.3, and a three-month limit for ensure that all acts of a certain type are following the laws. The last point is apparently an appeal to ensure compliance.